# Peak index in a mountain array in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve the [peak index in a mountain array](https://leetcode.com/problems/peak-index-in-a-mountain-array/) problem from leetcode.

here is the question.

Let's call an array arr a mountain if the following properties hold:

```
arr.length >= 3
There exists some i with 0 < i < arr.length - 1 such that:
arr[0] < arr[1] < ... arr[i-1] < arr[i]
arr[i] > arr[i+1] > ... > arr[arr.length - 1]
Given an integer array arr that is guaranteed to be a mountain, return any i such that arr[0] < arr[1] < ... arr[i - 1] < arr[i] > arr[i + 1] > ... > arr[arr.length - 1].
```

This is what i tried.

```
class Solution(object):
    def peakIndexInMountainArray(self, arr):
        """
        :type arr: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if len(arr) < 3:
            return -1
        lo = 0
        hi = len(arr) - 1
        while lo <= hi:
            mid = (lo + hi) // 2
            if arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1] and arr[mid] > arr [mid - 1]:
                return mid
            elif arr[mid] > arr[mid-1]:
                lo = mid + 1
            else:
                hi = mid - 1
```

on the three test case in the leetcode my code works when when i submit the code is ran on new test case where it fails and gives none as output. I couldn't find bug in my code

Here is the failed test case array

```
[3,9,8,6,4]
```

Comment: What happens when mid==0?

Comment: So i tired with this code  :  if ((mid == 0 or arr[mid - 1] <= arr[mid]) and
        (mid == n - 1 or arr[mid + 1] <= arr[mid])):
        return mid 
But still the same errot

Comment: For the failed test, `len(arr) - 1 = 4`, so the first `mid` is 2. Then you set `hi = mid-1`, so `hi` is 1. Then the second `mid` is 0, and the program crashes because `mid-1` is not a valid index. Given that the problem states that `0 < i < len(arr)-1`, you should start with `lo=1` and `hi=len(arr)-2`.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks your solution also uses less memory then mine solution

Comment: @user3386109 This is python, `arr[-1]` is not an error, it refers to the last element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't understand properly how it works. Here is the answer. if anyone can explain feel free

```
if len(arr) < 3:
            return -1
        lo = 0
        hi = len(arr) - 1
        while lo <= hi:
            mid = (lo + hi) // 2
            if arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1] and arr[mid] > arr [mid - 1]:
                return mid
            elif arr[mid] > arr[mid-1]:
                lo = mid 
            else:
                hi = mid
```